# SA_OAuthTwitterEngine Twitter authentication on iOS 5 (error -1012)

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios5

I'm using SA_OAuthTwitterEngine and it works fine for some accounts. But, gives (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.) for some twitter accounts.

It seems to work fine on ios 4. But not on iOS 5. anyone notices this problem?

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Yes... Change http to https in the `initOAuthWithDelegate` method inside SA_OauthTwitterEngine.m and this should fix the problem - like so:

```
self.requestTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
self.accessTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer, it helped me in Tumblr Login, I was working on Tumblr and it was failing OAuth for second time authorization. THANKS ONCE AGAIN.

Answer (score 2):

try find&replace http://twitter.com/oauth/ with https://twitter.com/oauth/
3x

Answer (score 0):

@NSDestroyer is correct. Just ran into this today, and changing to https solved the issues. Thanks!